# Add Folder to Spotlight Index in Yosemite

Tags: macos, spotlight

I found a link somewhere that uses `mdimport -f` command, however, when using it on the command line, I got the message that says

> warning, the -f option has been obsoleted, and does nothing.

So, how can I add a custom path into spotlight index in Yosemite (10.10)

Comment: Mavericks is 10.9. Are you using 10.9 or 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Yosemite @tubedogg